# how to move newest file in directory and then process the rest of the script

Tags: batch-file

so i'm trying to take one file at a time out of a directory that contains 2000 files and going up and move it to a different directory to be worked on by the rest of my script. the script is below. Right now i know the gswin64 line works when it is alone and i specify it a filename but not i'm sure with the variable yet.  But when i run this it will copy all the files in directory input to directory working before it runs the rest of the script. How do i make it do one at a time then process the script before copying the rest of the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "H:\documents\gs\input\*.*" /A-d /B /O:-D') do (move "H:\documents\gs\input\%%I" "H:\documents\gs\working"&goto filemoved)
:filemoved
```

Your original code would attempt to execute `move "H:\documents\gs\input\*.*" "H:\documents\gs\working"` which is why all of th files were moved. What you need to do is execute a directory list command with the switch parameters and supply that to the `for /f`. This form of `dir` will show names only. so you need to include the source directory name in the `move` command. You would also need to have the `"delims="` option to ensure that filenames containing separators are processed correctly, and the `/a-d` directory switch to ensure that directory names are not included. Since you are sorting in reverse-date order, the newest file will be selected first. After the first file is moved, you need to abort the `for` loop otherwise it will continue processing the entire list, transferring every file. The easy way here is to simply `goto` a label on the next line.

You've also used a `*.*` filemask, which will process all files, regardless of extension. Since you appear to want to process only `.pdf` files, you should probably change that filemask to suit.

```
for /F "delims=" %%x in ('dir H:\documents\gs\working\*.pdf /b') do set "FileName=%%x"
```

Again, you need to execute a `dir` command if you are using a `for /f`. There's no apparent reason why you wouldn't use the far simpler

```
for %%x in (H:\documents\gs\working\*.pdf) do set "FileName=%%x"
```

In either case, you probably want only the `name` part of the file, so `FileName` should be set to `%%~nx`, not `%%x`.

```
"C:\program files\gs\gs9.20\bin\gswin64" -o H:\documents\gs\output\"%FileName%" -sDevice=pdfwrite -dFitPage -dFIXEDMEDIA H:\documents\gs\working\"%FileName%"
```

Unbalanced quotes - the full pathname to the executable needs to be quoted since it contains a separator. Stray spaces after `\` will probably need to be removed.

It would be better imho to quote the entire filename, including drive and path rather than filename only.

```
del /q H:\documents\gs\working\*.*
```

`rm` is not a batch command. Note that this command will delete **ALL** files in `H:\documents\gs\working` - not just the `.pdf` files that you appear to be processing.

```
goto start
```

The space is required. `gotostart` is not an inbuilt command.